# Exception with opencv AND visual studio 2012 c++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem in my code, I implemented the transformer hough for the detection of circles the program stops at the beginning ( hand) ( overflow exception) the exception has been caused bay tha mat matrice

[image]

```
#include "opencv\highgui.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>

#define M_PI 3,1415926535

using namespace std;
//int** matr;
//unsigned char** mat;

double ConvertToRadians(double angle) {
return (M_PI / 180) * angle;
}


int main()
{
    IplImage *img=img=cvLoadImage("test.jpg");


    int n,m;
    IplImage *img_nvg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),img->depth,1);
    IplImage *dst=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img_nvg),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    IplImage* color_dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
    int flip=0;
    if(img->origin!=IPL_ORIGIN_TL)
        {
            flip=CV_CVTIMG_FLIP;
        }

    cvConvertImage(img,img_nvg,flip);
    cvCanny(img_nvg,dst,50,200,3);
    cvCvtColor( dst, color_dst, CV_GRAY2BGR );

    n=img->height;
    m=img->width;

int matr [300][300],x,y;
for (x=0;x<n;x++){
        for (y=0;y<m;y++){
            matr [x][y]=0;
        }
}
unsigned long mat[900][900];

CvScalar pixel;
for (int x=0; x < m; x++)
{
for (int y=0; y < n; y++)
{
    try{
        printf("nous somme ici \n");
pixel = cvGet2D(color_dst,y,x); // répérer le pixel (x, y)
printf("nous somme ici 2\n");
mat[y][x] = pixel.val[0]; // on remplit la matrice avec le niveau de gris d'une image
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        printf("erreur\n");
    }
}
}

int r=30,a,b;

cvNamedWindow("originale",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("originale",img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid problem in title: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648

Comment: 1) **Don't** use obsolete C syntax. Use C++. 2) OpenCV has `CV_PI`

Comment: the problem is in the stack of system , too muth calls in the program but i can't find the solution :/ help please

Comment: Comments in code should be in English on StackOverflow.